# A .NET custom attribute to perform impersonation?

Tags: .net, security, impersonation, custom-attributes

I have some methods that need to run as a certain service account, so I do the normal thing:

```
public DoSomeWorkAsServiceAccount() {
    ...
    // assume I am given tokenHandle
    WindowsIdentity newId = new WindowsIdentity(tokenHandle); 
    WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate();

    ...
    // do the work here
    ...

    impersonatedUser.Undo();
}
```

I'd like to avoid writing this code in every method, so I was thinking of creating a custom attribute:

```
[Impersonate(tokenHandle)]
public DoSomeWorkAsServiceAccount() {
    // do the work
}
```

So here are my questions:

1. Is this possible?
2. Can you show me something that will avoid code duplication?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think an attribute is the best way to implement a feature like this.  For the most part attributes merely act as meta-data on types and members (Aspect Oriented stuff aside).  You'd need to write something to check for that attribute, and re-route the method call accordingly.  If you already have some AOP code in place this shouldn't be much of a chore, but if you don't you'd likely be much better served by something like this:

```
public void DoWorkAsUser(tokenHandle, Action op)
{
  WindowsIdentity newId = new WindowsIdentity(tokenHandle); 
  WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate();

  op();

  impersonatedUser.Undo();
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
DoWorAsUser(token, MyMethod);
```

This allows you to centralize the impersonation code without having to mess around with reflection, codeweaving, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I wish we had AOP.  And BTW, your icon is awesome.

Comment: You're welcome!  I didn't put it in the example, but make sure you wrap your 'op' call in a try finally block and dispose the WindowsIdentity and WindowsImpersonationContext objects.

Answer (score 3):

I've don't have any code, but you could try using [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.org/) to do this. You could create an OnMethodInvocationAspect which arranges the security stuff before calling the method code. eg

```
public class ImpersonateAttribute : OnMethodInvocationAspect
{
  public override void OnInvocation(MethodInvocationEventArgs eventArgs)
  {
    WindowsIdentity newId = new WindowsIdentity(tokenHandle); 
    WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate();

    eventArgs.Proceed() // Call the code in the actual method.

    impersonatedUser.Undo();
  }
}
```

The above is a complete guess, but by suggesting it, I may have given you a valid option.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't realize that attributes were just data, and a framework was needed to make it "do stuff".